# Gimbal Lock and Rotationmatrix questions

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rotation

I have got some questions related to rotations on 3D objects. I am using a right-handed system with row-major matrix.

I've been programming a drawer, which draws lines based on the orientation of the current rotation.

My questions:

If I always use a different axis on each rotation, based on the new orientation, can gimbal lock still happen when I only rotate once? For example:

```
    matrix.rotate(angle,newaxis) // newaxis is based on the current orientation
```

I tested many situations with the rotation matrix. I found out that each column represents a vector of the new coordinate system. Like `matrix.column[0]` is `x-axis` and `matrix.column[1]` is `y-axis`. My questions is this: I need to get x, y, z values to 'move forward and draw a line. Like this

`moveX(current.x+d*orientation.x)`.

I found out that the solution was to grab the values from the ***first row*** of the matrix. **But why is that so?**